# $\oint \frac{dz}{z^4 - 1}$ along $|z|=2$ using Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I factorized $\frac{1}{z^4 - 1}$ into $\frac{1}{(z-1)(z+1)(z-i)(z+i)}$ and I know that it will be somehow solved by partial fraction but not able to proceed further. Answer for this question is showing $0$.

Comment: Do you know Residue Theorem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: I haven't reached to the Residue Theorem yet . This question is given in Cauchy Integral Formula problems

Comment: Please insert a / the question (also) in the text of this OP. Please **show** the own attempts to solve the problem, at any rate please provide more context. To use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula (and not the Residue Theorem), we may need indeed to get the partial fraction decomposition for $1/(z^4-1)$ - so where is the problem, what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

We have $$\frac{1}{(z-1)(z+1)(z-i)(z+i)}=\frac{1}{4(z-1)}-\frac{1}{4(z+1)}+\frac{i}{4(z-i)}-\frac{i}{4(z+i)}$$

Now use that $$\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{z-a}=2\pi i$$ where $|a|<2$.

Comment: Are you sure that that is the correct fraction decomposition of $1/(z^4-1)$? I'm getting something different, and WolframAlpha says so too.

Comment: @jasnee Thank you! Fixed.

Comment: It should still say $...-\frac{i}{4(z+i)}$ at the end, but other than that it works :)